# git commit -m not working

Tags: git, git-commit

I have been committing to my local repository today with `git commit -a` and entering my commit messages. Everything fine.

At the end of the day I wanted to commit a small change with a single line commit, so I used `git commit -m "some message"` and got the following:

```
On branch ChartFeature
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/ChartFeature' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   SomeFolder/Scripts/app/SomeScript.js

no changes added to commit
```

What have I done wrong?

How do I get git to allow `commit -m` again?

Footnote: After failing with `-m` a few times and seeing nothing wrong with `git log origin/ChartFeature..HEAD` I tried `git commit -a` as before and it worked (as expected) though `git commit -m` still does not.

Comment: Does this work?: git commit -am "some message"

Comment: As the message says -  do **git push** to yours origin twice .

Comment: You should pre-emptively do a `git add .` before every commit.

Comment: did you add your changes to staging area using git add command

Comment: Sounds like sarcasm, tastes like sincerity. I was at home and just got in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git commit -m
```

does only work when you did a `git add something` before!

That is all there is to that! In other words: you haven't added (staged) anything; thus you can't make a commit!

```
git -a
```

adds (certain) types of changes automatically; -m does not!

Your status messages tells you:

Changes **not staged** for commit:
        *modified:   SomeFolder/Scripts/app/SomeScript.js*

Answer (score 5):

Probably you need to merge 'origin/ChartFeature' before you push any changes.

Follow this steps

First, add all changes by using

> git add -A

Then commit your changes

> git commit -m "message"

Before doing push on the branch just pull once this will merge your code with the remote branch. If you want to review this code before merge then you can use git fetch

> git pull origin the branch

then push the changes on the respective branch

> git push origin the branch

Answer (score 2):

> Changes not staged for commit:

You need to `Add` first then do `Commit`.

```
$ git commit -am 'Message'   # changes are staged & commit
```

Comment: No explanations whatsoever. Not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the modified files:
use:

```
git add SomeFolder/Scripts/app/SomeScript.js
```

and then use :

```
git commit -m"Some message"
```

and then

```
git push origin <the branch>
```

Comment: The file change is a modification, not add... the file is already added.

Comment: The file is not staged for commit hence you cannot commit -m

Comment: You need to add it , in order to make a commit.

Comment: Nope - the file change was added but the git add . was necessary (as your first code sample states)

Comment: Perhaps the confusion came from not understanding the meaning of `add`. add is used for more than just putting the file into the repo the first time. add must also be called after each change, to tell git that you want those changes "added' to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

First add the modified files to git using any of the following:-

git add -A stages All

git add . stages new and modified, without deleted

git add -u stages modified and deleted, without new

I will prefer git add -A.

then try to commit, it will work